# PrimeFaces/JSF resources folder not reconized

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use an image in my XHTML page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
 <h:body>

   <h:form>
        <h:graphicImage  library="default" value="img/image.jpg" />
   </h:form>

  </h:body>
</html>
```

[image: and this is my folder Tree]

and the resutl is that the file is not loaded

Comment: `<h:graphicImage  library="default" name="img/image.jpg"/>` - just replace `value` by `name` and it should do.

Comment: @Tiny you are right, however there seem to be other errors within the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead, use the `name` attribute when you use the `library` attribute, or alternatively put the full path in `value` attribute.

1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
 <h:body>
   <h:form>
        <h:graphicImage  library="default" name="img/image.jpg" />
   </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
 <h:body>

   <h:form>
        <h:graphicImage  value="/resources/default/img/image.jpg" />
   </h:form>

  </h:body>
</html>
```